# How can I make Facebook-like notification system without cron job?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, notifications, cron

I'm working on a php based reminder system which is capable to view almost real time (10 min period is just fine for me) notification on the browser (inside a div sounds good) and inform the user about a scheduled task or something like that. The problem is I'm miserable about php and my server doesn't support cron-job for some security reasons. I may change my hosting company with a cron supported one, if I have to.

Is there any way to make it work in these conditions?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: sockets? node? JS timers?

Comment: Imma make a research about using websockets. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Webworker in your page to load the script of the notifications every 10 minutes.

```
    var interval = 720000;
function loadNotifications(){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.open("GET","/notifications", false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);

    var JsonObj = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    xmlHttp = null;
    postMessage(JsonObj);
    setTimeout("loadNotifications()",interval);

}

loadNotifications();


};
```

Then just create a web worker for this script that would handle the responses every 10 minutes like adding the results to a dialog or something.

Comment: Or as @Zarathuztra said you could work with Websockets that would be cool, and it will be in realtime.

Comment: It sound very logical to me. I'm gonna try it and feedback here later. Thanks for your help!